# Pandas: what is the data-type of object passed to the agg function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have been curious about what exactly is passed to the agg function

```
Id      NAME   SUB_ID
276956  A      5933
276956  B      5934
276956  C      5935
287266  D      1589
```

So when I call an agg function, what exactly is the datatype of x.

```
df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: set(x))
```

From my own digging up, I find x to be `<type 'property'>` but I dont understand what exactly it is. What I am trying to do is compress the records into one row for any particular group. So for id 276956 , I want to have A,B,C in one cell under the Name column. I have been doing it by converting it into a set but its causing me some grief with Nan and None values. I was wondering whats the best way to compress in a single row. If these are numpy arrays then I don't really need to convert but something like

```
df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: x)
```

throws an error

Answer (score 6):

You working with `Series`:

```
print (df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: print(x)))
0    A
1    B
2    C
Name: NAME, dtype: object
3    D
Name: NAME, dtype: object
0    5933
1    5934
2    5935
Name: SUB_ID, dtype: int64
3    1589
Name: SUB_ID, dtype: int64
```

You can working with custom function, but output has to be aggregated:

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    return set(x)

print (df.groupby('Id').agg(f))
             NAME              SUB_ID
Id                                   
276956  {C, B, A}  {5933, 5934, 5935}
287266        {D}              {1589}
```

If need aggreagate `join`, numeric columns are [omited](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns):

```
print (df.groupby('Id').agg(', '.join))
           NAME
Id             
276956  A, B, C
287266        D
```

If `mean`, `string` columns are omited:

```
print (df.groupby('Id').mean())
        SUB_ID
Id            
276956    5934
287266    1589
```

---

More common is used function [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) - see [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
def f(x):
    print (x)
    return ', '.join(x)

print (df.groupby('Id')['NAME'].apply(f))
Id
276956    A, B, C
287266          D
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

Comment: Glad can help you. Please dont forget `accept` my or another answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> df[['Id', 'NAME']].groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x))
           NAME
Id             
276956  A, B, C
287266        D
```

The `x` in this case will be the series for each relevant grouping on `Id`.

To actually get a list of values:

```
>>> df[['Id', 'NAME']].groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: x.values.tolist())
             NAME
Id               
276956  [A, B, C]
287266        [D]
```

More generally, `x` will be a dataframe for the relevant grouping and you can perform any action on it that you could normally do with a dataframe, e.g.

```
>>> df.groupby('Id').agg(lambda x: x.shape)
        NAME SUB_ID
Id                 
276956  (3,)   (3,)
287266  (1,)   (1,)
```